# Failed to load resource: unsupported URL gap://ready iOS14

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ios14

I have a problem with new version of iOs (14.01) this version add some kind of security browser. Im trying to add in a white list using WKAppOundDomains to solve this quickly.

[.plist info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGZe6.png)

I get the following error adding to .plist the last showed into the picture:

ERROR Internal navigation rejected -  not set for url='gap://ready'

I´ve been looking for this error and find the following. If I add into the config.xml this   it supposedly fix the issue but I get another error:

[Process] 0x7f959983ba20 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=60212] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID = 32, domain = NSURLErrorDomain, code = -1002

Both error are running in blucle.

I try add something like this into index.html but didnt work neither ''

If I open with iOS13 works but I have to do it in IOS14 to solve a issue. Some ideas?. Thanks.